# How can I edit WooCommerce email template via Wordpress Child Theme functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress, Avada Theme, and WooCommerce. My problem is with the WooCommerce emails. I do know the address where email template php files are stored, but IF possible, it would be great to customize these templates via Child Theme **functions.php**. Is this possible? Can anyone provide me with an answer or at least, a reference?

If necessary, I can insert admin-new-order.php and functions.php here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emails for WooCommerce are stored in the Plugins folder, while your child theme will be in the theme folder.  Any changes you want made unfortunately can't be done through the theme editor in the admin panel, and will have to be made directly to the WooCommerce files.

Comment: Your are right. Thank you. With a closer look at WooCommerce email options I find the complementary answer and added it to the tail of your response.